limit of $\{a_n\}$ depend on starting value
For what values of $\alpha$ does the sequence defined by the recurrence relation
$a_1 = \alpha$, $a_{n+1} = 1 - e^{-a_n}$
converge to $0$?

this is what I tried to do:
I assumed that the sequence $\{a_n\}$ converges, so:
$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = L$,
which implies:
$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} a_{n+1}$.
Substituting into the recurrence relation gives:
$L = 1 - e^{-L}$.
Solving this equation, I found that $L = 0$ is a fixed point. However, when I tested it with some values of $\alpha$, it seems that the sequence does not always converge to $0$.

I need help
figuring if I did mistakes in my way
and for what values of alpha the limits is 0
Thanks for your help!
{tbh I'm not good in formating so I asked chatGPT to help me reformat my question}

So for what values of $\alpha$ does it converge to this value?

English language has uppercase and lowercase letters. Not only that, punctuations as well! Jokes apart, please format your post to make it more readable.

Some hint: study $f: x \mapsto 1-e^{-x}$ and its derivative, when is it grater or smaller than one (in absolute value)? Or directly $f(x)-x$

First of all, observe that if $a_i<0$ then so is $a_{i+1}$. This is because
$$a_{i+1} = 1-e^{-a_i} < 1-e^{0} = 0.$$
Additionally, by Taylor Series bounding with $a_i<0$ we have $$a_i-a_{i+1} = a_i+e^{-a_i}-1 > \frac{a_i^2}{2}$$
so once we have a negative value, all further terms in the sequence are more negative. This alone doesn't show that the sequence goes to $-\infty$ (for example consider $a_n =  -2+\frac{1}{n}$), but combining the $\frac{a_i^2}{2}$ lower-bound of consecutive differences forces this to be the case.
You've already mentioned that $0$ is a fixed point, so if any term is $0$ all further terms will be $0$. If any term $a_i$ is positive, then $a_{i+1} = 1-e^{-a_i} \in (0, 1)$. Then, with a term in $(0, 1)$, all further terms will be in $(0,1)$. We can then note that $a_i\in (0, 1)$ implies $a_{i+1} = 1-e^{-a_i} < a_i$ by Taylor Series bounding, so the sequence is monotonically decreasing and bounded below. Hence the sequence converges, so it must converge to $0$ by virtue of being the only fixed point.
With all of this analysis, we have that the sequence converges to $0$ if $\alpha \geq 0$ and goes to $-\infty$ if $\alpha<0$.

The OP claims that $0$ is a fixed point, not necessarily the only one. So to be complete, you need to show that there is no other fixed point in $[0,1]$.

This directly follows from my last paragraph statement on $a_{i+1}<a_i$ anyway.

No. If there were another fixed point, $a_i$ could decrease to it instead. Overall your approach is helpful, but needs a bit more to be a full answer.

No, for such a fixed point alpha in (0, 1) we would have 1-e^{-alpha}<alpha, contradicting it being a fixed point.
